# S10 plus zxing NPM scanner is not working in PWA

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, hybrid-mobile-app

I am not able to scan the actual bar-code and Qr-code sticker, the size sticker is almost one finger and when take the picker and sent it over mail Or take the printout and in bigger size the IT is working fine for me.***This is only not working in Samsung S10, in rest of Mobile it is working fine.*** Any suggestion will helpful me. Thanks in Advance!